# I want to each other reflected by calculating the input contents of the three input tags in each

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

**In the current situation, only it is reflected in two to calculate the input contents of one of the input tag**

・This is only an example

・Anything is good if the input contents of the input tag is mutual reflect

```
<div id="target"></div>
<script src="mithril.min.js"></script>
<script>
var App = {
  controller: function() {
    return {
      temp: m.prop(10)
    }
  },
  view: function(ctrl) {
    return m("div", [ 
      m("input", {onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.temp), value: ctrl.temp()}),
      m.component(App2, {value: ctrl.temp()}),
    ]);
  }
};
var App2 = {
  controller: function() {
      return {
          m1: function ( param ) {
            return {'a': parseInt(param)+1, 'b': parseInt(param)+2, 'c': parseInt(param)+3};
          },

          m2: function ( param ) {
            m2Obj = this.m1(param);
            return {'d': parseInt(m2Obj['a'])+4, 'e': parseInt(m2Obj['b'])+5, 'f': parseInt(m2Obj['c'])+6};
          }
      }
  },
  view: function(ctrl, args) {
    return m('div',
      m("input", {onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.m1(args.value)), value: ctrl.m1(args.value)['a']+","+ctrl.m1(args.value)['b']+","+ctrl.m1(args.value)['c']}),
      m("input", {onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.m2), value: ctrl.m2(args.value)['d']+","+ctrl.m2(args.value)['e']+","+ctrl.m2(args.value)['f']})
    );
  }
};
m.mount(target, App)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs in `App2` do not interact properly because the `App2` component is passed the *result* of the `m.prop()` — not the `m.prop` function itself — therefore they cannot pass their results back.

There is a problem with the logic of your functions somewhere that I couldn't find: mathematical operations are returning `NaN`. But then, I'm not sure what the expected logic is (with the abstract function and property names it's difficult to follow!). Good luck with that!

---

I found it difficult to follow the flow of data and assignments, so took the liberty of refactoring your code slightly: rather than assigning the `m.prop` to objects and querying those properties by name in the views, the prop is passed directly. I also have it the same name — `value` everywhere to avoid confusion. Obviously this may not be appropriate when your application needs to deal with more data points, but I found it easier to reason about this specific example with these simplifications:

```
var App = {
  controller: function() {
    return m.prop(10)
  },
  view: function(value) {
    return m("div",
      m("input", {
        onchange: m.withAttr("value", value), 
        value: value()
      }),

      m(App2, value)
    )
  }
}

var App2 = {
  controller: function() {
    return {
      m1: function ( value ) {
        return {
          a: parseInt(value)+1, 
          b: parseInt(value)+2, 
          c: parseInt(value)+3
        }
      },

      m2: function ( value ) {
        m2Obj = this.m1(value)

        return {
          d: parseInt(m2Obj.a)+4,
          e: parseInt(m2Obj.b)+5,
          f: parseInt(m2Obj.c)+6
        }
      }
    }
  },
  view: function(ctrl, value) {
    return m('div',
      m("input", {
        onchange: m.withAttr("value", value(ctrl.m1(value()))), 

        value: 
          ctrl.m1(value()).a+","
         +ctrl.m1(value()).b+","
         +ctrl.m1(value()).c
      }),

      m("input", {
        onchange: m.withAttr("value", value(ctrl.m2)), 

        value: 
          ctrl.m2(value()).d+","
         +ctrl.m2(value()).e+","
         +ctrl.m2(value()).f
      })
    )
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, App)
```

Comment: For example, possible to cross-convert the binary and decimal?
<input type text>.<input type text>.
After I enter a binary number to one of the input tag , conversion to decimal.
After I enter the decimal to the other of the input tag, conversion to binary number

Comment: Yeah, definitely possible.